# How to spread object as method input parameter but not as arguments array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, named-parameters, spread-syntax

I have a function expecting multiply parameter and an input object that contains information with same key name as parameter field name, take a small example, e.g

```
const input = {
   firstName: 'first',
   lastName: 'last',
   age: 19
}

function test(firstName, lastName, age, otherThings) {
   console.log('firstName: ', firstName):
   console.log('lastName: ', lastName):
   console.log('age: ', age):
}
```

Right now I have to call it either by the `dot` notation of my input object, or using the spread which turns into an array then use index there

```
// call method 1
test(input.firstName, input.lastName, input.age, 'other');

// call method - I know it's kinda ugly but just an available way
test(...[input][0], ...[input][1], ...[input][2], 'other');
```

I am wondering if there is any other way that can use the idea of `spread operator` but instead of mapping into an array, spread the object as `flatMap` then automatically map them into the method parameter fields, I know the `...input` may not work as `input` was an object not an array so it's not iterable.

```
// is it possible?
test(...input.someAction?, 'other');
```

This would help when my input object as pretty large and want to figure out a smart way of executing it without modifying the method signature, please note I CANNOT modify the method signature or implementation, we can consider it as an interface method and we can only determine how to execute it on our side

Comment: Why not just take the object as a parameter?

Comment: Maybe use Python instead. More seriously, though, it is unfortuante you can't do this in JS.

Comment: @HereticMonkey because I cannot modify the method signature or implementation as mentioned, which can be considered as an unchangeable interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test(...Object.values(input), 'other')
```

would kinda work, but of course that will break as soon as the object gets more properties or contains them in a different order - it will not put properties into arguments for the respective parameter names, that is impossible. For a proper solution, you should change the `test` function to take an options object:

```
function test(options) {
   console.log('firstName: ', options.firstName):
   console.log('lastName: ', options.lastName):
   console.log('age: ', options.age):
}
```

or with destructuring:

```
function test({firstName, lastName, age, otherThings}) {
   console.log('firstName: ', firstName):
   console.log('lastName: ', lastName):
   console.log('age: ', age):
}
```

Then you can call it properly using

```
test(input)
```

or also with object spread

```
test({...input, otherThings: 'other'})
```

Comment: thanks! That's kinda works, unfortunately I cannot modify the method signature or implementation which can be considered as an unchangeable interface, I can only change on the caller side..

Comment: Then you definitely should use `test(input.firstName, input.lastName, input.age, 'other');`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = {
   firstName: 'first',
   lastName: 'last',
   age: 19
}

function test(firstName, lastName, age, otherThings) {
   console.log('firstName: ', firstName);
   console.log('lastName: ', lastName);
   console.log('age: ', age);
}

test.apply(this, Object.values(input));
```

You could send in the values with apply.  However object key order is not guaranteed so this isn't a "great" solution.